# Unable to upload file to ftp server using php

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp

I am trying to upload file to FTP server using php but it is not getting uploaded.

Code:

```
   $response =<<<RESPONSE
    <cdm:Response>
    <cdm:header exportTime="{$export_time}" baseVersion="{$baseline_snapshot_id}" version="{$this->snapshot_id}">
            <cdm:countryCode>{$this->domain}</cdm:countryCode>
            <cdm:description>{$description}</cdm:description>
            <cdm:environment>{$destination}</cdm:environment>
            <cdm:name>{$name}</cdm:name>
    </cdm:header>
    <cdm:Status>{$this->status}</cdm:Status>
    </cdm:Response>
    RESPONSE;

   $handler = fopen($log_file_name, 'w');
   fwrite($handler, $response);
   fclose($handler);

   $server = "adoshi.dev.com";
   $ftp_user_name = "adoshi";
   $ftp_user_pass = "*******";
   #$source = $handler;
   $mode = "FTP_ASCII";
   $dest = "/home/adoshi/ftp_folder";
   $connection = ftp_connect($server);
   $login = ftp_login($connection, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
   if (!$connection || !$login) { die('Connection attempt failed!'); }
   $upload = ftp_nb_put($connection, $dest, $handler, $mode);
   if (!$upload) { echo 'FTP upload failed!'; }
   ftp_close($connection);
```

I have provided all login credentials proper and so still wondering that why it is not uploading to remote server using php.

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What happens or doesn't happen? What error messages turn up? What is the stuff in the top section? You will have to provide some more details for anybody to be able to help you.

Comment: Ah, strike that with the top section, I didn't see the first line.

Comment: I do not get any error messages and there is nothing there on the ftp_folder also and so it is very amusing to notice.

Comment: just edit the question and remove the irrelevant part ...

Comment: I have pasted portion of code in there and which first line you are pointing too ?

Comment: hy again you have an syntax error in your code  
look for this line : $upload = ftp_nb_put($connection, $dest, $handler, $mode);

and change it to 

$upload = ftp_put($connection, $dest, $handler, $mode);
and dont forget to accept the answer regard streetparade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to create a file handler to upload them you just need the path to that file and the filename like this

```
$destFile= "test.htm";
$lokal_file = "test.htm";
$upload = ftp_put ($connection_id, $destFile, $lokal_file, FTP_ASCII);
```

Comment: I tried doing this but still it is not working out for me. Thing is am not getting any kind of errors and so am not able to track what is actually happening.

Comment: did you tryed adding this to your script? 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

Comment: hy again you have an syntax error in your code look for this line : $upload = ftp_nb_put($connection, $dest, $handler, $mode); and change it to $upload = ftp_put($connection, $dest, $handler, $mode); and dont forget to accept the answer regard streetparade